# php image blob wont show

Tags: php, mysql, blob

So I am trying to show an image from my mysql database. The image is saved as a blob format. I made seperate php file for fetching the image. I then call this file from where I want to show the image like so:

```
<img src="image.php?id=3" />
```

This is the file that fetches the image:

```
<?php
    require 'scripts/connect.php';

    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
        $q = $db->prepare("SELECT image FROM products WHERE id = '$id'");
        $q->execute();
        $data = $q->fetch();

        header("content-type: image/jpeg");
        echo $data["image"];
    }
?>
```

But when I try and run this code no image shows up. Instead I get this annoying broken link image thing:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGGTF.png

Comment: did you sure that all images is type of jpeg ?

Comment: What is size of image? did you try to open image file from some (text/hex) editor?

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding on how to use prepared statements. Use placeholders in your SQL that will be prepared, don't use user input there. User input should go to `execute()`.

Comment: I am sure the image is of jpeg format and yes I just face palmed over my prepared statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't do what you expect.

Try to change

```
$q = $db->prepare("SELECT image FROM products WHERE id = '$id'");
```

in - if `id` field is numeric one; if isn't, add single quote -

```
$q = $db->prepare("SELECT image FROM products WHERE id = $id");
```

Your example didn't work as you were passing to query `$id` placeholder and not his value (you dind't concatenated it)

Of course with that method you're not save by [SQL Injection](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) at all, so you should use pepared statement that way

```
$q = $db->prepare("SELECT image FROM products WHERE id = :id");
$q->execute(Array(":id" => $id));
```

## Edit

As OP told me that $data['image']; is a bitstream, I will suggest to use something like:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'. base64_encode($data['image']). '" alt='imagename'>;
```

or if your echo goes directly into `src` attribute:

```
echo 'data:image/jpg;base64,'. base64_encode($data['image'])
```

Comment: I'd suggest that you use placeholders instead of entering user input into the SQL statement that will be prepared. No matter if it is escaped or not. Therefore change it to  `$q = $db->prepare("SELECT image FROM products WHERE id = :id");` and `$q->execute(Array(":id" => $id));`

Comment: @vhu: you're totally right, I was only suggesting to OP how to make his code work ... I was integrating my answer while my phone start ringing :)

Comment: Thanks for you supreme answer. I tried the fix, but the same error occurs.

Comment: @user3511194: we should know how the url is encoded into db ... maybe is a relative one so your "echo" couldn't be sufficient there ...

Comment: Okay. How can I see the url?

Comment: In `$data["image"]` a "bit stream" or an url? Because maybe i dind't understand this part of your question ....

Comment: $data["image"] is the blob data stored in the database, so im guessing bit stream

Comment: I tried with the editied code. But still the same error.

Comment: @user3511194: I'm pretty sure my answer is good. Maybe you have some other errors that we can't understand "from here" and "from your question". Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
header("content-type: image/jpeg");
```

with

```
header("content-type: image/png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT image FROM products WHERE id = :id");
$query->execute(array(":id" => $id));
$data = $q->fetch();
```

For serving the image, use

```
$mime = pathinfo($data['image'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($data['image']);
```

**Note:**

- `readfile()` needs the image path to where the images are stored.
- if you are use PHP >= 5.4, `$query->execute([":id" => $id]);` 
  can be used instead of 
  `$query->execute(array(":id" => $id));`

Comment: This didnt work for me. I got the error:  Warning: readfile() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\haugaard\image.php on line 17

Comment: that's because `readfile` needs the exact path to the location of the image.